# Add/Change image on a SharePoint List image column for Gallery view

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, modern-experience, pnp-powershell, image

I have a SharePoint Online list column that accepts an image called Image. I would like to populate this content using PowerShell, specifically using the PnP module, as the rest of the script I'm writing is leveraging this already.

Finding this question asked at [Add/Change image on a SharePoint List image column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292558/add-change-image-on-a-sharepoint-list-image-column), I'm getting partial success when uploading the content.

PowerShell code that creates the list item, uploads the file, and sets the list item's Image field to the uploaded content:

```
            $AddRecord = Add-PnPListItem -List $list -Values @{
                Firstname = $Comparison.FirstName;
                LastName = $Comparison.LastName;
                Initials = $Comparison.Initials;
                Office = $Comparison.Office;
                Department = $Comparison.Department;
                OfficePhone = $Comparison.OfficePhone;
                MobilePhone=$Comparison.MobilePhone;
                Title="$($Comparison.Firstname) $($Comparison.LastName)"
            }

            $InsertID = $AddRecord.Id
            $EmployeePhoto = Join-Path "C:\Photos" "$($Comparison.Initials).JPG"
            if (Test-Path $EmployeePhoto) {
                $FileUploaded = Add-PnPFile -Path $EmployeePhoto -Folder "/sites/intranet/SiteAssets/Employee Directory Photos"
                // $FileUploaded
                Set-PnPListItem -List $list -Identity $InsertID -Values @{Image = "{serverRelativeUrl: '$($FileUploaded.ServerRelativeUrl)'}"}
            }
```

When reviewing the individual list item through the web UI, I can see the image:
[image]

However, in the Gallery view for the same list, the image is blank (instead of undefined):
[image]

If I manually upload the image to the record, the Gallery view works just fine, and in this case, I find the image in `/SiteAssets/Lists/<some guid>/filename.jpg`.

How do I get an image to be uploaded correctly for use in a Gallery view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Add/Update image columns in SharePoint/Microsoft Lists using PnP PowerShell](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/10/13/add-update-image-columns-in-sharepoint-microsoft-lists-using-pnp-powershell/) article, you can update the image column using:

```
Set-PnPListItem -List "Logo Universe" -Identity 12 -Values @{"Image" = "{'type':'thumbnail','fileName':'PnP-PowerShell-Blue.png','fieldName':'Image','serverUrl':'https://contoso.sharepoint.com','serverRelativeUrl':'/sites/SPConnect/SiteAssets/Lists/dbc6f551-252b-462f-8002-c8f88d0d12d5/PnP-PowerShell-Green.png'}"}
```

You have to set the `serverRelativeUrl` as well as the other properties of image column.

---

In order to show the image properly in gallery view, make sure image is referenced like below in gallery view JSON:

```
[$fieldName.serverRelativeUrl]
```

Where `fieldName` is internal name of the image column. You can get the internal name of your Image column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Source**: [SharePoint Online: All you need to know about New Image column type](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/06/all-you-need-to-know-about-new-image-column-type-in-sharepoint-online/) - check comments section